# python - how merge lists of strings to become one

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

i'm trying to merge two lists of strings in python ,like:

```
['this','is','list one'] ,['and','list two','combined']
```

to become one list.

```
"+" and "join".
```

doesn't work for me

the original code:

```
 for word in passwordslist:
    frequencyList+=[word[x:x+N] for x in xrange(len(word)-N+1)]
```

(trying to collect all the N-grams of string passwordlist)

Comment: + should work, as should extend(). Show us exactly the code you're using.

Comment: for word in passwordslist:
        frequencyList+=[word[x:x+N] for x in xrange(len(word)-N+1)] but there is an error because of +=

Comment: @user1387682 Please edit your question to add the code there.

Comment: That code is adding a list of lists. You're really going to have to show some context here or we can't figure out what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Did you initialize `frequencyList` to `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the list?

```
frequencyList = []
for word in passwordslist:
    frequencyList += [word[x:x+N] for x in xrange(len(word)-N+1)]
```

You could also write this as one comprehension:

```
frequencyList = [
    word[x:x+N]
    for word in passwordslist
    for x in xrange(len(word)-N+1)
]
```

Comment: your answer is correct -i didn't initialize the list, but why doesn't python initialize when i'm at the loop?

Comment: Why don't you look at the error message you got without the initializer?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> first_list = ['this', 'is', 'list one']
>>> second_list = ['and', 'list two', 'combined']
>>> first_list.extend(second_list)
>>> print first_list
['this', 'is', 'list one', 'and', 'list two', 'combined']
```